# Can I port mobile applications written in Appcelerator into cordova (using VS 2015)?

Tags: cordova, titanium, appcelerator

I am not familiar with Appcelerator or cordova, but my company need to develop a simple mobile application which has some simple buttons for first release but we need to do it very quickly and I don't think that we can do it in house.

we are familiar with visual studio development and JS and the idea is that after initial development, we bring the outsource code to developed more in house possibly with Apache cordova and visual studio 2015.

As both system uses HTML 5 and JS, I think we may be able to port over most of the code. Am I right?

Are they compatible in the way that for example we can port c/c++ from windows to Linux (we knew that it is possible but with some care and restriction).

Is there any point that I should consider if I plan to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator and Cordova are both using JavaScript for the logic, so you might be able to re-use some of that. But while Cordova uses HTML/CSS for the UI, Appcelerator uses native UI components using JS factory methods. It does have a XML/TSS MVC but it's unlikely you can re-use any of that. Also, any interaction with system API's like geolocation will be using very different APIs on both platforms.